# How can I get Youtube MostViewed URL

Tags: html, youtube

If a user types a video's name, it will link to that name's most-viewed Youtube video. For Example, if a user searches for "Sam Smith", it will redirect to Sam Smith's Most-Viewed video. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the command line?

If so, this perl program gives you the url of the most viewed video for a given user. This assumes that YouTube doesn't change their HTML format anytime soon.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Enter user name: ";
chomp ($user = <STDIN>);

my $url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/".$user."/videos?sort=p"; # sort=p means sort by popularity

# open the web page
open F, "wget -q -O- $url|" or die "Could not wget $url";

my $mostViewedUrl = 'ERROR';

foreach $line (<F>){
    # Since the urls are sorted by popularity,
    # we want the first url only.
    if($line =~ /.*<h3 class="yt-lockup-title ">/){
        $mostViewedUrl = $line;
        last;
    }
}

$mostViewedUrl =~ s/.*href="([^"]+).*/$1/;
$mostViewedUrl = 'youtube.com'.$mostViewedUrl;
print "Most viewed link: $mostViewedUrl";
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube provides a whole lot of API's for developers to extract data from its database without causing security issues for a user. You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for the API's provided by the youtube. 
For that you just need to sign in as a developer and create a project in there, which you can learn [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

One such method is that you can determine the maximum number of views a video of a channel have and you can find that video. [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#brandingSettings.channel.unsubscribedTrailer) is the link which may be useful.

Comment: Link only answers are not good. The link target may move and the answer becomes meaningless. The answers should be as self contained as possible.